# Append to file after application restarts- Phonegap

Tags: javascript, file-io, cordova

In phonegap is there a way to get the length of a file when the application starts and the writer is created so that you can a writer.seek() to that position and append to the file. It currently appends once the application is running but over writes the file everytime the application restarts. Below is my code for the writer. The writer is created globally.

I am using phonegap 1.2.0 running on Android 2.3.3

```
var writer = new FileWriter("mnt/sdcard/mydocs/text.txt");


function appendFile(text) {
  try{
    writer.onwrite = appendSuccess;
    writer.onerror = appendFail;
    writer.seek(writer.length);
    writer.write(text);
    }catch(e){
      alert(e);
      }
}

function appendSuccess() {
    alert("Write successful");
  }

  function appendFail(evt) {
    alert("Failed to write to file");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a bug. In the latest versions of PhoneGap it is fixed. However, we no longer support:

```
new FileWriter(pathToFile);
```

now you need to do:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(FS) {
    FS.root.getFile("empty.txt", {"create":true, "exclusive":false}, 
        function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(
                 function(writer) {
                    console.log("Length = " + writer.length);
                    console.log("Position = " + writer.position);
                    writer.seek(writer.length);
                    console.log("Position = " + writer.position);
                 }, fail);
        }, fail);
}, fail);
```

Sorry about the incorrect first answer. Apparently you can't pass a [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry) to the [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) constructor you need to pass a [File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) which is gained by calling the [FileEntry.file()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry_file) method.

Gotta love this convoluted W3C spec.

Comment: I tried updating to cordova-1.7.0 and creating a new FileWriter by passing it a file entry but it still overwrites my old file. My new code is below:      

 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("text.txt", {create:true, exclusive: false}, gotfile, fail);
    } 
  function gotfile(fileEntry){
      writer = new FileWriter(fileEntry);
    } 

writer.length always returns 0 the first time the application is run even if there is text in the document. Am I getting the length the wrong way now?

Comment: It worked after updating to 1.7.0 and passing the file rather than the file entry. Thank you for your help and quick responses!

Comment: No problem, it's always fun when I learn something new about my own project.